# Sequence number that reset if year changes

Tags: excel-formula, string-concatenation, excel-2013

I need a formula that reset the sequence 001 if year changes

[image: Here's My Example]

[image: i tried but i dont know how to reset the sequence number]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GgcmPiWNh7R8Uj1xG5wdWK8w-tI8J995-6I8YnalLo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: it there more simplier for this formula? 

=concatenate(right(year(C3),2),"-",TEXT(IF(RIGHT(YEAR(C3),2)=RIGHT(YEAR(C4),2),1,""),"000"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following in `D3`:
`=text(iferror(if(year(C3)<>year(C2),1,left(D2,3)+1),1),"000")&"-"&right(year(C3),2)`

Or if you want the result in column B change `D2` to `B2` in the formula.